# Sort django rest framework paginated list by date in vue

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, pagination, vuex

A list of items needs to be sorted (ASC and DESC) by date on click. This list of items is paginated by Django Rest Framework Pagination. Therefore, the first page of items contains just 15 results. The default sorting is newest date first.

Whenever the list is sorted, the current state is sorted by .sort(), through a mutation in Vue. This works, however, just for the current state which only contains the list of items that are in the first page (assuming the user didn't go to next page). This causes the order only to be valid for the results per page, but not for all results.

To solve this, I could do an API request to return the results in the correct order, but my question is, is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the sorting in the backend when you do pagination, basically, your API method should support a sorting parameter, sort the list according to that parameter, paginate the results after sorting and return paginated results.

Your client does not have access to all the data, so you can not do the sorting on the client side when there's pagination, results need to be sorted **before** a slice is taken.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So basically, there's no other way to do the sorting than I thought.